# Why are iPhone4 and iPhone5 (iOS 7) not recognizing bluetooth devices?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, iphone

when I go to Settings -> Bluetooth and turn it on, devices (both iPhone 4 and 5, iOS7) start searching for devices with bluetooth, but never find anything. On the other hand, when I search from Android, iPhones are always found and can be paired, but sometimes not connected because of not supporting some devices (for iPhone 4 is written for me that Xperia Z2 is not supported).

The problem is that I'm trying to discover nearby beacon, but as I've said, I cannot discover anything with iPhones. Android discovers it without problem.

How can I solve it, so my devices find surrounding devices sending bluetooth signals?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by searching for devices over at Settings > Bluetooth ?

Comment: Because below is panel for devices that are recognized. Where else should I search for it?

Comment: What do you intend to do after the list shows up?

Comment: List never shows up and that's what I don't understand. Why can't it discover nearby devices with bluetooth on? I wouldn't want to anything with list, just want to make sure that iPhone is catching signal for beacon.

Comment: As far as I've noticed, It usually doesn't show up any Android phones but it shows other bluetooth enabled devices like Pebble Smartwatch or Gecko Tags.

Comment: Well, it's just weird that even iPhone doesn't show other iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 4 has bluetooth whereas iPhone 5 has AirDrop. So they are not compatible with each other.

That is answer to a part of your question that iPhone doesn't recognise other iPhone (5 and 4).

Comment: Ok, I've tried iPhone 4 to iPhone 4 too.

Answer (score 0):

Different smartphones have different Bluetooth versions depending on when they were made.

Your Xperia Z2 has `Bluetooth 4.0`, which has something called `Bluetooth Low Energy`, which is used to communicate between devices.

iPhone 4's (not iPhone 4S') have `Bluetooth 2.1` and don't support this.
iPhone 4S' and above on the other hand have `Bluetooth 4.0` and can hence detect the other smartphones.

This is hence the reason why AirDrop is only supported on iPhone 4S' and above.

Additionally this is also the reason why on your iPhone 4 you can't see your other iPhones and phones that don't have a Bluetooth version of `4.0` or higher.